# Maven: how to add a dependency as provided for runtime, but explicitly for test?

Tags: maven, unit-testing, scope

In my current project that runs on a JBoss server it is required to add all dependencies as `provided`if they are provided by JBoss. However for my unit-tests I do need those libraries without the JBoss server providing them (i.E. javaee-api), but I cannot add the same dependency twice with different scopes.

How can I add a dependency as `provided` for runtime, but as `test` for unit tests?

Comment: I have my doubts that your unit tests need things like javaee-api? So from my impression those are integration tests which means you should make a separate module where you run your integration tests and you can define different dependencies also with different scope (test) ...

Comment: MediaType-constants are defined in the JavaEE API, which I definitely need for my tests.

Comment: Ok. One exception found. I don't know javaee-api in detail..is this the only one?

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess that there are several constant-like classes that could be utilized in testing.

Comment: @TwoThe did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

A `provided` dependency is available on the test classpath, so setting the scope to `provided` should be fine. See also the definition of `provided`:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: It would be provided by the JBoss server, which is however not started for the unit-tests, so the tests fail with unresolved imports.

Comment: The source says: "This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive." I would have thought that, since it should be on the test classpath, the imports should work. My understanding is that compile, test and provided dependencies are all available if you start tests.

Comment: Provided means that there will be some external system that provides the library later. Which is the case once the ear file runs on JBoss, but it is not the case if the test cases are run during the test Maven step. So it will compile, but it will not run, as no one actually provides the jar during test.

Comment: This is the "ideological" meaning of provided. Actually, it just means that the artifact is not packed into the war/ear you are using. From the description, I would have assumed that for tests, all compile,test and provided dependencies are on the runtime classpath. But maybe the document I linked is misleading and I am wrong. It would be strange to filter out provided dependencies for tests, though. Tests should have all the dependencies available.

Comment: Could you give an example of an unresolved import in a test, that should have been resolved from a provided dependency?